# Using "new" to override BindableObject.SetBinding extension method not working

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, overriding, new-operator

How is the SetBinding not being called? I used the "new" keyword to create a new SetBinding

```
public partial class TestContentView : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty ValueProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(TestContentView), typeof(object), typeof(object), default, BindingMode.OneWay, null, OnValuePropertyChanged);
    public static readonly BindableProperty DummyProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(TestContentView), typeof(object), typeof(object), default, BindingMode.OneWay);

    public TestContentView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public object Value
    {
        get => GetValue(ValueProperty);
        set => SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
    }

    public object Dummy
    {
        get => GetValue(DummyProperty);
        set => SetValue(DummyProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnValuePropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        ((TestContentView)bindable).SetBinding(DummyProperty, "Path");
    }

    public new void SetBinding(BindableProperty targetProperty, BindingBase binding)
    {
        //this is never called
    }
}
```

The code for Xamarin.Forms.BindableObjectExtensions.SetBinding is below.

```
public static void SetBinding(this BindableObject self, BindableProperty targetProperty, string path, BindingMode mode = BindingMode.Default, IValueConverter converter = null, string stringFormat = null)
{
    if (self == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("self");
    }

    if (targetProperty == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("targetProperty");
    }

    Binding binding = new Binding(path, mode, converter, null, stringFormat);
    self.SetBinding(targetProperty, binding);
}
```

On the xaml side, I just have a simple call to create the view.

`<controls:TestContentView Value="{Binding Name}" />`

Comment: `SetBinding` is not virtual, you will always be calling the one in `BindableObject`. You would have to use reflection to find the right new method for this code to do what you want it to do.

Comment: There are multiple problems with what you tried to do. 1) `TestContentView` isn't `static`. you can't put an extension method in it. 2) The correct syntax for defining an extension method is `public static void SetBinding(this BindableObject self, ..)`. 3) Extension methods are not a hierarchy. `new` makes no sense there. If you were able to make that definition, the compiler would refuse to compile your attempt to use it - because now there would be TWO definitions of that extension method. It would complain about the ambiguity. The compiler won't attempt to "pick one" - it will give error.

Comment: ... Nor is any of this needed. If you want to write your own binding logic, to use within that class, then simply call it as a method of the class: `this.SetBinding(myBindableObject, ...);` (You can omit `this.` - I just included it for clarity.) Or to avoid confusion, you could change the name from `SetBinding` to something else. Maybe `SetBindingOn`, to indicate it is acting on the first parameter.